# System.DivideByZeroException on high numbers in C#

Tags: c#

So I've been trying to write a program in C# that returns all factors for a given number (I will implement user input later). The program looks as follows:

```
//Number to divide
long num = 600851475143;

//initializes list
List<long> list = new List<long>();

//Defines combined variable for later output
var combined = string.Join(", ", list);

for (int i = 1; i < num; i++)
{
    if (num % i == 0)
    {
        list.Add(i);
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

However, after some time the program starts to also try to divide negative numbers, which after some time ends in a  System.DivideByZeroException. It's not clear to me why it does this. It only starts to do this after the "num" variable contains a number with 11 digits or more. But since I need such a high number, a fix or similiar would be highly appreciated. I am still a beginner.
Thank you!

Comment: You need to do some more debugging yourself. Make this the simplest reproducible example possible: get rid of the loop and give us a single number that breaks the code. Keep reducing this example until you have just the absolute minimum code necessary to create it and often you'll find the issue yourself that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I strongly suspect the problem is integer overflow. `num` is a 64-bit integer, whereas `i` is a 32-bit integer. If `num` is more than `int.MaxValue`, then as you increment `i` it will end up overflowing back to negative values and then eventually 0... at which point `num % i` will throw.

The simplest option is just to change `i` to be a `long` instead:

```
for (long i = 1; i < num; i++)
```

It's unfortunate that there'd be no warning in your original code - `i` is promoted to `long` where it needs to be, because there's an implicit conversion from `int` to `long`. It's not obvious to me what would need to change for this to be spotted in the language itself. It would be simpler for a Roslyn analyzer to notice this sort of problem.

Comment: Thank you! Now it's working as it should. I will accept the answer as soon as the page allows me to.